# Differenet way to GET data from the same form multiple times

Tags: php, get

I have a form which has a name text area. The form leads to the main page where I use `$_GET['name']` and then store that into a session and use it later. I need each of these sessions to be unique so I used the `$_GET` to help name them.

The problem I'm facing now is that I need to use that form multiple times and store multiple sessions based off of that `$_GET` but every time I `$_GET` it changes the previous sessions name.

What is a better way to deal with this?

Something like :

```
if (isset($_GET['name']))
{
    $_SESSION['name_' . $_GET['name']] = $_GET['name'];
}
```

Comment: Could you provide I code sample, have no idea what you're trying to do.

Comment: And... sessions by default are unique for each user. You shouldn't have to DO anything to make a session unique.

Comment: @Leeish I'm not using this for users, name was just an example.

Comment: Users... people accessing the page. Each person who hits your page will start a unique session and that session will persist until it expires. You still shouldn't need to do anything to make them unique.

Comment: @AmazingDreams added a little bit of what I'm trying to achieve

Comment: @Leeish take a look at my edited question snippet.

Comment: This should work, though I have no idea what it is supposed to do, and I have no idea how you are EVER going to access that session data again...

Comment: @AmazingDreams this is why I'm asking this. I need a way to create that unique session name based off of their name or some other unique identifier but don't know how to.

Comment: @MichaelN if you just want to save some per-user data, simply use `$_SESSION['name'] = $_GET['name'];` This session variable will be bound to the user, it won't get into someone elses browser or whatever. As I said, it is impossible to EVER access the data you set here in any 'normal' way.

Comment: @AmazingDreams this isn't for many people to use one time. This is for one person to use many times which is why I require some sort of uniqueness to create a new session each time.

Comment: So, as for your requirement in last comment: Set `$_SESSION['name'] = $_GET['name'];` and use it wherever you want to use it.

Comment: @AmazingDreams but I need to set MULTIPLE of these sessions. Are you saying I can have multiple sessions called name with different values of GET?

Comment: You could use an array? Sorry for misunderstanding you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you want unique? try this:

```
$_SESSION['my_unique_key'] = time();
$myS = $_SESSION['my_uniqie_key'];
$_SESSION['name_' . $_GET['name'] . '_' . $myS] = $_GET['name'];
```

note that

```
 $_SESSION['my_unique_key']
```

will hold unique key (almost unique) since it gets the timestamp. So each time you set the session it will get unique key, so each time form is submitted will have different timestamp which will make unique.

Comment: @AmazingDreams why is this bullshit? This seems like a clever way to do it?

Comment: Obviously this question is based on missing knowledge/understanding of PHP's Sessions.

Comment: Since this is the closes I got to a proper answer I'll give you the tick. Thanks.

Comment: I still think whatever you are doing... there must be a better way. But I am glad you found the answer you were looking for.

Comment: @AmazingDreams maybe explain why this wouldnt solve the problem Michael is trying to solve?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand you correctly, but if you wish to exchange some values between many sessions of the same user, browser or whatever, I would suggest to use cookies. They are page independent, of course one can disable cookies.